# Sencha Touch 2 How to restrict datepicker showing future dates

Tags: validation, extjs, datepicker, sencha-touch-2

Could any one please help me to restrict Sencha Touch datepicker not displaying / allowing future dates in the desired datepicker field.

Please

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented as follows,

```
{
    xtype : 'datepickerfield',
    label : 'date',
    picker : {
        yearFrom : 2000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an override for changes like this. Otherwise you need to change it for all date pickers across the app.

```
Ext.define('App.override.picker.Date', {
    override: 'Ext.picker.Date',

    config: {
        yearFrom: 1970,
        yearTo: 2070, // you can use a fixed number or: new Date().getFullYear() + 10, 
        monthText: 'Month',
        dayText: 'Day',
        yearText: 'Year',
        slotOrder: ['month', 'day', 'year'],
        doneButton: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following configurations to restrict year input.

```
Ext.create('Ext.picker.Date', {
    yearFrom: 2000,
    yearTo  : 2015,
    //or you can use
    minValue: new Date(1980,1,20),
    maxValue: new Date()
});
```

Also check the [`setYearTo()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-setYearTo) and [`updateYearTo()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-updateYearTo) methods.

The component doesn't allow to restrict actual month and day input but you can validate it afterwards.